# Installing vmware tools on Ubuntu host where nothing on Desktop

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu 16.10 on VMware Workstation 12 Player running on Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit 6.1.7601, Service Pack 1.  I have installed VMware tools gone to

```
> Manage > Virtual Machine Settings > Options > Shared Folder
```

added c:\Shared to the shared folders list and set it to "Always Enabled".

I have problems when I go to set up the shared directory on the Ubuntu host.  The typical directions are as exemplified [here](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525). That is, I am supposed to use a file, VMwareTools.x.x.x-xxxx.tar.gz, that is supposedly in the Desktop directory.  However my Desktop directory is completely empty so the directions are of no use.  I do a search for "VMwareTools.x.x.x-xxxx.tar.gz download" but only find links that assume the file is already in the Desktop directory.

I make a directory /home/me/shares and run the following

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

I then try

```
mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /home/me/shares
```

and get

```
error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device
```

I run

```
vmware-hgfsclient
```

and get

```
 Shared
```

but I cannot find a directory called Shared.

I put a file, filename.h, in the c:\Shared the Windows system but

```
sudo find / -name filename.h -print
```

on the Ubuntu host, returns no result

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by deleting the Ubuntu host and reinstalling it on VMware Workstation 12 Player.  I had initially installed it of VMPlayer 6.  When I upgraded to VMware Workstation 12 Player, it kept the installed version of Ubuntu but did not upgrade its capabilities.

After I reinstalled Ubuntu, the vmware tools installation files were in

```
/media/userName/"VMware Tools"
```